# How to get a "close" icon floating on the top right corner of a v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, responsive-design, frontend, vuetify.js, web-frontend

currently I have a v-dialog that opens when the window does, and I'm trying to implement a v-icon in the top right corner of my v-dialog. Here is a wireframe: [image]

I cant seem to get the icon in the top right corner of my dialog. I have tried creating a transparent div, putting the v-dialog into containers, etc, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my code:

```
<v-dialog 
        v-model="adPopup"     
        presistent
        @click:outside="closePopup" 
        max-width="700px">
          <Advertisements
          :adPopup="adPopup"
          @doNotShowValue="doNotShowVal"
          @closePopup="closePopup">
          </Advertisements>
      </v-dialog>
```

Advertisements.vue

```
<template>

            <v-card class="ad-card">
                <v-card-text class="pa-0">

                    <v-img max-width="100%" class="img-height" src="@/assets/PopUp.png">                    
                        <v-icon class="close-popup">mdi-close-circle</v-icon>
                    </v-img>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions class="card-actions">
                    <v-btn 
                    depressed
                    outlined
                    class="mr-1 mb-2 white--text ml-2" color="white" @click="closePopup(0)" style="text-transform: none;">Close</v-btn>
                        <v-checkbox
                        style="color: #ffffff; border-color: white"
                        color="white"
                        class="mt-2 ml-2 custom-checkbox"
                        v-model="doNotShow">
                        </v-checkbox>
                        <p class="mt-2 white--text">Do not ask me again</p>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-icon>    <font-awesome-icon icon="times" /></v-icon>
                    <v-btn class="mb-2 white--text view-products mr-2" color="#4D95B6" @click="closePopup(1)" style="text-transform: none;">View Produts</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>    
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to either allow overflow on the `v-card`, or put the button in a container around the card.

```html
<v-card class="overflow-visible">
  <v-btn
    class="close-popup"
    icon="mdi-close-thick"
    color="black"
    size="x-small"
    elevation="0"
  />
  ...
```

or

```html
<div class="position-relative">
  <v-btn
    ...
  />
  <v-card>...</v-card>
</div>
```

Then you can use absolute positioning to get it to the right and then translate it to the corner:

```css
  .close-popup {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    border: 3px solid white !important;
  }
  .close-popup .mdi {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
```

Have a look at the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: wouldn't the icon be cutoff by the width of the v-card? When I tried something similar, the circle would get cutoff instead of floating off the edge of the card @MoritzRingler

Comment: Oh, I guess the playground did not reset a setting, sorry. You are right, you need to get around the `overflow:hidden` on the `v-card`. Have a look at the updated answer and playground